# matplotlib.pyplot: How to plot single graph with different Colormaps and a Legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting separate figures for each attribute and label for each data sample. Here is the illustration:

[image]

As illustrated in the **the last subplot (Label)**, my data contains seven classes (numerically) (0 to 6). I'd like to visualize these classes using a different fancy colors and a legend. Please note that I just want colors for last subplot. How should I do that?

**Here is the code of above plot:**

```
x, y = test_data["x"], test_data["y"]
# determine the total number of plots
n, off = x.shape[1] + 1, 0
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (40, 15)
# plot all the attributes 
for i in range(6):
    plt.subplot(n, 1, off + 1)
    plt.plot(x[:, off])
    plt.title('Attribute:' + str(i), y=0, loc='left')
    off += 1

# plot Labels
plt.subplot(n, 1, n)
plt.plot(y)
plt.title('Label', y=0, loc='left')

plt.savefig(save_file_name, bbox_inches="tight")
plt.close()
```

Comment: For each subplot loop over the labels and plot a separate series for each label?

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis sorry, could not get your idea completely.

Comment: I see seven labels (0-6) in the sample image. So, you want to show seven (or six?) different colors in each of the subplots above? Are you sure you want to do this? This will be quite the color overload with questionable readability. If you intend to do this, Ari has already told you the route you probably have to go down by masking the arrays for label and plotting each in a different color.

Comment: @Mr.T oh sorry, its 7 classes not six. Thanks for the correction. Secondly I do not need for all the subplots. I just want different colors for my last subplot (Label).

Comment: What is the input for the label plot and how did you plot it? Looks like a step function of an array [2, 4, 1, 6, 0,...] plotted against the index (0, 1, 2, 3...) but who knows.

Answer (score 1):

First, just to set up a similar dataset:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random((100,6))
y = np.random.randint(0, 6, (100))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(6, figsize=(40,15))
```

We could use [`plt.scatter()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) to give individual points different marker styles:

```py
for i in range(x.shape[-1]):
    axs[i].scatter(range(x.shape[0]), x[:,i], c=y)
```

Or we could mask the arrays we're plotting:

```py
for i in range(x.shape[-1]):
    for j in np.unique(y):
        axs[i].plot(np.ma.masked_where(y!=j, x[:,i]), 'o')
```

Either way we get the same results:

[image]

Edit: Ah you've edited your question! You can do exactly the same thing for your last plot only, just modify my code above to take it out of the loop of subplots :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. But I need colors for the last subplot not for all.

Comment: I see! You can use the same methods illustrated above (`plt.scatter()` or loop over each y-value and mask), but for your last plot only. I'll leave that to you!

Comment: A scatter plot is structurally different from line plots, as it creates a different matplotlib object. You cannot simply transfer the concept.

Comment: @Mr.T, I appreciate that a scatter plot is a different thing to a line plot, but this use case is *exactly* what a scatter plot is for (different markers for bits of your dataset). A line plot doesn't make sense in this context anyway, as the line segments go between the categories. Both code blocks produce identical figures, so I'm happy that either are appropriate for answering the question (or what the question was before it was edited).

Comment: @Mr.T do you have any idea or clue to do that in line plot.

Comment: In general, you have to [construct it from individual line segments](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html) as a Line2D object in matplotlib has exactly one color in contrast to the PathCollection object created by scatter(). I have an idea of how to simplify this process but won't have time today to explore this. Tbh, I would rather drop the last plot and color the background of each segment in the other subplots with different colors according to the label value. This is probably easier to read.

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you for the wonderful suggestion. Let me try it, but when you will find the time, please try it. It will be great to learn things from other in different way.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis After masking, some empty spaces are created as the color change. How can the plotted line remain same?

Comment: Think what that line is representing. Each point is a label value, so the line between two different labels can't be either color, so is left blank. You might need to think of a different visualization for your data?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, we imitate the matplotlib [step function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.step.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.step) by creating a [LineCollection](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection) to color the different line segments:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

#random data generation
np.random.seed(12345)
number_of_categories=4
y = np.concatenate([np.repeat(np.random.randint(0, number_of_categories), np.random.randint(1, 30)) for _ in range(20)])
#check the results with less points
#y = y[:10]
x = y[None] * np.linspace(1, 5, 3)[:, None]
x += 2 * np.random.random(x.shape) - 1
#your initial plot
num_plots = x.shape[0] + 1
fig, axes = plt.subplots(num_plots, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(10, 8))
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat[:-1]):
    ax.plot(x[i,:])
    
#first we create the matplotlib step function with x-values as their midpoint
axes.flat[-1].step(np.arange(y.size), y, where="mid", color="lightgrey", zorder=-1)
#then we plot colored segments with shifted index simulating the step function
shifted_x = np.arange(y.size+1)-0.5
#and identify the step indexes 
idx_steps, = np.nonzero(np.diff(y, prepend=np.inf, append=np.inf))

#create collection of plateau segments
colored_segments = np.zeros((idx_steps.size-1, 2, 2))
colored_segments[:, :, 0] = np.vstack((shifted_x[idx_steps[:-1]], shifted_x[idx_steps[1:]])).T
colored_segments[:, :, 1] = np.repeat(y[idx_steps[:-1]], 2).reshape(-1, 2)
#generate discrete color list
n_levels, idx_levels = np.unique(y[idx_steps[:-1]], return_inverse=True)
colorarr = np.asarray(plt.cm.tab10.colors[:n_levels.size])
#and plot the colored segments
lc_cs = LineCollection(colored_segments, colors=colorarr[idx_levels, :], lw=10)
lines_cs = axes.flat[-1].add_collection(lc_cs)

#scaling and legend generation
axes.flat[-1].set_ylim(n_levels.min()-0.5, n_levels.max()+0.5)
axes.flat[-1].legend([Patch(color=colorarr[i, :]) for i, _ in enumerate(n_levels)], 
                     [f"cat {i}" for i in n_levels],
                     loc="upper center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.15),
                     ncol=n_levels.size)
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [broken barh](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.broken_barh.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.broken_barh) plots or color this axis or even all axes using [axvspan](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvspan.html?highlight=axvspan#matplotlib-axes-axes-axvspan).